# Is Yast Firewall the same as IPTables?

Tags: linux, firewall, opensuse

I am confused about Yast Firewall on OpenSuse. Is Yast a different firewall to IPTables? Or is it simply a tool used to control the firewall that is already installed on the system?

**Edit: Fix typos.**

Comment: From what I can tell [Yast](https://github.com/yast/yast-firewall) is a front end for iptables.  Almost everything that manages a firewall on Linux is a front end for iptables. The exception being nftables which is new filtering replacement for iptables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAST firewall module is a frontend to iptables (being managed by the SuSEfirewall2 script package) that is being phased out in openSUSE Leap 15.0 and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 in favour of firewalld.

You can find the configuration files for SuSEfirewall2 in /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 which the YAST firewall plugin manipulates.

/etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2.d/services on the other hand lists all the services that you can add to various zones in SuSEfirewall2, in case you need to add custom services that are not included in rpm packages installed in the system.

Unless you have specific need to support older releases (such as 42.x or SLES 12) you should not worry too much about it but instead spend time learning how firewalld works.